# FFMpeg Question about paket pts, dts and duration parameters

Tags: ffmpeg, libavformat

According with the remuxing.c example I have using the flollowing 3 lines of code:

```
Packet.pts= av_rescale_q_rnd(Packet.pts, pAVStreamIn->time_base, pAVStreamOut->time_base, static_cast<AVRounding>(AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF | AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX));
Packet.dts= av_rescale_q_rnd(Packet.dts, pAVStreamIn->time_base, pAVStreamOut->time_base, static_cast<AVRounding>(AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF | AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX));
Packet.duration= av_rescale_q(Packet.duration, pAVStreamIn->time_base, pAVStreamOut->time_base);
```

The code works but not using an rtsp camera as source. I obtain an error at av_interleaved_write_frame function.
Please have a look at the following log report:

```
AudioIndex Packet.pts: 0, Packet.dts: 0, Packet.duration: 160
AudioIndex Packet.pts: 120, Packet.dts: 120, Packet.duration: 160  
AudioIndex Packet.pts: 312, Packet.dts: 312, Packet.duration: 160
AudioIndex Packet.pts: 432, Packet.dts: 432, Packet.duration: 160
AudioIndex Packet.pts: 632, Packet.dts: 632, Packet.duration: 160
AudioIndex Packet.pts: 752, Packet.dts: 752, Packet.duration: 160
AudioIndex Packet.pts: 952, Packet.dts: 952, Packet.duration: 160
AudioIndex Packet.pts: 1072, Packet.dts: 1072, Packet.duration: 160
AudioIndex Packet.pts: 1272, Packet.dts: 1272, Packet.duration: 160
AudioIndex Packet.pts: 1392, Packet.dts: 1392, Packet.duration: 160
AudioIndex Packet.pts: 1592, Packet.dts: 1592, Packet.duration: 160
AudioIndex Packet.pts: 1712, Packet.dts: 1712, Packet.duration: 160
VideoIndex Packet.pts: 9223372036854775808, Packet.dts: 9223372036854775808, Packet.duration: 0
```

As you can see the pts, dts, duration parameters relative to audio stream is ok, the video parameters abolutally not.
How can I do to rewrite the video parameters?
Can anyone explain?

Comment: Looks like your video packets don't come with timestamps so ffmpeg assigns them AV_NOPTS_VALUE which is what you see. If you know of and are sure of the framerate, generate using that, or assign relative wallclock time by setting `use_wallclock_as_timestamps` with value `true` as a format option for the demuxer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but, after having added the line of code

pAVFormatContext->use_wallclock_as_timestamps= true;

I obtain the error:

Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 1: 12704101795272 >= 12704101795272
av_interleaved_write_frame() Error!!!